# Popup with Grid as well as submit button using Extjs

Tags: extjs

In our application we are using Extjs. Now I need a pop up with a grid and a cancel and submit button. So that I can select some records from the grid and save the record to DB.

I tried `Ext.Window` for popup.

I think `items` attribute in the `Ext.Window` can hold only one type of object ( means the object of `Ext.grid.GridPanel` or form). But I need both controls.

How can I implement both controls with in a popup window?

Please give your valueable information about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `items` can be an array. It's in the docs.

Comment: But I have given object of both, grid and form. but showing only first object. Given like as following,  items: [grid,form].

Comment: var myData = [['ddd', '1111'], ['eee', '2222']];
                var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({ fields: [ { name: 'FLD', type: 'string' }, { name: 'VAL', type: 'string' } ] });
                store.loadData(myData);
                var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                    store: store,
                    loadMask: true,
                    columns: [ { header: 'FLD', dataIndex: 'FLD' }, { header: 'VAL', dataIndex: 'VAL' } ],
                    viewConfig: {
                        forceFit: true
                    }
                });

Comment: var form = Ext.widget('form', { layout: { type: 'vbox', align: 'stretch' },
                    border: false,
                    bodyPadding: 10,
                    fieldDefaults: { labelAlign: 'top', labelWidth: 100, labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold' }
     ,buttons: [{ text: 'Submit', handler: function () {
                            if (this.up('form').getForm().isValid()) {
                                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                                this.up('window').hide();
                            } } }] });

Comment: var myWin = new Ext.Window({ layout: 'fit', title: 'Test', width: 400, height: 300, closable: true, buttonAlign: 'center', items: [grid,form], modal: true });
myWin.show();

Comment: Update the question, don't post it in the comments. Also, look at the docs for layout fit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50039/discussion-between-sajith-a-k-and-evan-trimboli)

Comment: The first line of fit layout: "This is a base class for layouts that contain a single item that automatically expands to fill the layout's container."

Comment: Thank you Evan, If I removed the "layout: 'fit'", both objects are displayed. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Given you're code submitted in the comments (btw, you can edit your question to include in the question).

You can either add multiple objects to the `items` array or, in this case, I would add a buttons bar to the bottom (`bbar`)

Here is code demonstrating this, Additionally here is working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4cp):

```
        var myData = [
            ['ddd', '1111'],
            ['eee', '2222']
        ];
        var store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [{
                name: 'FLD',
                type: 'string'
            }, {
                name: 'VAL',
                type: 'string'
            }]
        });
        store.loadData(myData);
        var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
            store: store,
            loadMask: true,
            //renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            columns: [{
                header: 'FLD',
                dataIndex: 'FLD'
            }, {
                header: 'VAL',
                dataIndex: 'VAL'
            }],
            viewConfig: {
                forceFit: true
            }
        });

        var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
            title: 'My Title',
            height: 400,
            width: 600,
            items: [
            grid
            ],
            bbar: [{
                text: 'Save',
                handler: function(btn) {
                    alert('Save!');
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Cancel',
                handler: function(btn) {
                    alert('Cancel!');
                }
            }]
        });
        window.show();
```